# change _id string to base64 encoded string in mongodb via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, base64

By default mongodb generates some random string like `5548087025c7f79259525eff` its type is ObjectId. Instead of that random string i want to use base64 encoded string so that it will always start from `alphabet` because I want CRUD on embeded documents which is not possible if id starts from integer according to my understanding. also store as string instead of ObjectId. Better if solution is using mongoose.

I can encode string to base64 using nodejs as in my case. but i dont know where to change this default behavior ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `_id` property in your schema and set the `type` option as `String`. You can either set a `default` value as a function to generate the value, or manually set it when you create the document.

```
    _id: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true }
```

Comment: good i solved using this var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var  Test = new Schema({
 _id: { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true, default: function(){ 
  
  var b64 = new Buffer(new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID().toString()).toString('base64');
  return b64;
  } },
 title: String,
 body: String,
 
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', Test);